# Laravel Count rows where column value is 1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hey so i am trying to do an upvote downvote system and I am only using 1 table, the table columns are

```
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
      $table->integer('voter_id')->unsigned();
      $table->foreign('voter_id')->references('id')->on('users');
      $table->boolean('vote_type')->default(0);
      $table->integer('commentable_id');
      $table->string('commentable_type');
      $table->string('unique_vote')->unique();
```

Basically I am trying to count how many votes the comment has but only where the `vote_type is == 1` and also the reverse for downvotes where the value is `0`

I was thinking about doing this with 2 different tables as it would make counting easier but I also dont want a large database.

i know of `{{$comment->votes->count()}}` but this returns the total rows regardless of the vote_type value and I am wondering if anyone has a solution or knows of a way while keeping the queries low.

Comment: I don't know laravel, but I'll bet it has a `->where()` function in a query that allows you to filter the rows.

Answer (score 4):

Why you do it like this

```
public function showCart() {

        $votes = Vote::where('vote_type',1)->count();
        // do stuff and then return the count with the actual data & view

    }
```

You cant chain like this

```
$votes = Vote::where('vote_type',1)->where('something',$something)->count();
```

if you want the result for the logged in user

```
$votes = Auth::user()->votes->where('vote_type',1)->count();
```

I hope you get the point here, you dont have to do the count in blade

Comment: Will this be adding thousands of queries on the front end if there is thousands of comments each with a vote?

Answer (score 1):

Too late to answer this question, but in general `groupBy` on a collection can be a good option for this

```
$votesInGroups = Vote::all()->groupBy('vote_type');
```

if you want to refine the data:

```
$votesInGroups->map(function($group, $key){
  // assign keys so that its meaningful
  if($key == 1) {
     return [
       'upvotes' => $group->count();
     ];
  }
  // yada yada yada
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just creating another relation and then enquing it with the main call. eg
comments class

```
public function upvotes()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\General\Votes', 'commentable')->whereVoteType(1);
}
public function downvotes()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\General\Votes', 'commentable')->whereVoteType(0);
}
```

--

```
public function index($category_slug, $subcategory_slug, $post_slug)
{

  return view('pages.forum-post', [
    'post' => Post::With('comments','comments.user','comments.votes','comments.upvotes','comments.downvotes','comments.user.UserProfile')->whereSlug($post_slug)->firstOrFail()
  ]);
}
```

--
blade

```
@if ($comment->upvotes)
  {{$comment->upvotes->count()}}
@endif
@if ($comment->downvotes)
  {{$comment->downvotes->count()}}
@endif
<hr />
```

Comment: You should get through sql 101, just to undestand your logic on a db level.

Comment: i understand that im doing 2 queries to check the same db and pulling all rows just to get a count where i could just pluck say... id. but at least this is better than doing 2 queries per comment. im happy with my 6 queries for a forum page.